# Why the Openssl signature verification needs the original file to verify its signature?

Tags: security, encryption, openssl

I signed an encrypted file (org-enc-file.txt) with the following command:

`# openssl dgst -sha1 -sign priv.pem org-enc-file.txt > file.txt.sig`

The signed file was sent to a System B that has all(public key) elements to verify and decrypt the file(file.txt.sig).

in the external system I used this command :

`openssl dgst -sha1 -verify public.pem -signature file.txt.sig org-enc-file.txt`

It says that verification OK only when the original encrypted file (org-enc-file.txt) is used as the last parameter of the command.
why the command *openssl dgst -sha1 -verify* needs the original file , is it always mandatory to send the original file with the signed file ?

Comment: How big is the "signed file" and the original file? Anyway, Stack Overflow is not a place to ask non-programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks, the size of each one is  512 octets

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. (Also search for Signature Schemes with Appendix (SSA) and Probabilistic Signature Schemes with Recovery (PSSR)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature you create with the command

```
# openssl dgst -sha1 -sign priv.pem org-enc-file.txt > file.txt.sig
```

**only** contains the signature, **not** the content of the original file you signed with. So when verifying the signature, you need the original file as well.

Comment: Your answer responds to my question. Is there a way to have the signature included in the encrypted file, without sending both of them ?